# How to change the default font family in Flutter

Tags: flutter, fonts, themes, font-family

How can I change every text of my app to use a specific font? I can change them individually by using the `TextStyle()` but how can I make my app default to a specific font? Can you show me how?

Comment: this link may solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64549111

Comment: What is the syntax to do this for CupertinoApp?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can change the default font family of your Flutter app by following the below steps:

**1. Add your font files into your project folder.** Say **`Project Folder > assets > fonts > hind`**.

**2. Declare the font family with font files with style in your project's `pubspec.yaml` file as (An example):**

[image]

3. In the `MaterialApp` widget of your main class file, define the default font family as:

[image]

Comment: @Rasoul707 are you sure you followed the steps correctly?

Comment: Its worth mentioning that a hot reload WILL NOT work. You need to stop the app and rebuild.

Answer (score 55):

If you want to use one of these [Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) then use the official [google_fonts](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts) package from the material team.

- add to pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
```

- Override the default font like this

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme(
      Theme.of(context).textTheme,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue with google_fonts it doesn't work with fontWeights that well.

Answer (score 12):

add [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) to pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
```

use fontFamily function

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    fontFamily: GoogleFonts.lato().fontFamily,
  ),
);
```

remember to import google fonts

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
```

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked with all text widgets just when I wrote it twice -

```
ThemeData(
   fontFamily: 'Varela',             // <-- 1
   textTheme: Theme.of(context)
      .textTheme
      .apply(fontFamily: 'Varela'),  // <-- 2
),
```

Comment: what is the context in this case?