# Change all children's font family in Flutter

Tags: flutter, text, widget, font-family

Is there a straight forward way to change the font family to a widget and all its children?

my thought was to have an inherited widget and store the font family and call it to get that when creating every text widgets and set its style, but I prefer a simpler way.

Comment: if I get what you want , check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237031/how-to-change-the-default-font-family-of-a-flutter-app

Comment: if you want juste for a party of widges, you have to create a shared style and use it with your widgets

Comment: @Anna thanks for you answer, but what I beed is to change that at runtime

Comment: @Anna yes but that is alot of work I have a about a hundred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the widget whose descendants you want to change (e.g. `MyWidget()`) in a `Theme` Widget. For example:

```
Container(
 child: Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
              textTheme: TextTheme(<your changes here>),
              ),
          child: MyWidget()
        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I believe this the best approach!