# Flutter when is SF Pro Display or SF Pro Text used and how to assign them to a Text widget?

Tags: flutter

I use the following two Text widgets in my app:

```dart
Text('12,23123,123.123 asdASD',
    style: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',
    )),
Text('12,23123,123.123 asdASD',
    style: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: '.SF UI Display',
    ))
```

However, both are displayed with the same `fontFamily`.

[image: Flutter SF Pro display and text issue]

The iOS typography docs say the following:

> For SF, use Text for text that’s smaller than 20 points; use Display for text that’s 20 points or larger.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/

How can I apply the different front families to my Text widgets?

Comment: Check this flutter article on how you can custom fonts https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the default font family of a Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237031/how-to-change-the-default-font-family-of-a-flutter-app)

Comment: SF is the default Flutter font for iOS, there should be no need to add a custom font

Answer (score 0):

The [related GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82995) to this question is currently under review by the Flutter Engineers and it seems that it is still in progress atm. Another related issue linked to this is this [GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63507), [as mentioned by the Flutter team](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63507#issuecomment-756280856), the issue is yet to be identified.