# how to add font family into in main.dart flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and struggling to add font family in my code..already updated my pubspec.yamal with OpenSans fonts.. now how to add font family into this main. dart material app widget??

> fontFamily: "OpenSans",

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: theme.copyWith(
        colorScheme: theme.colorScheme.copyWith(primary: Color(0xff075e54),secondary: Color(0xff128C7E),

        ),
      ),
      home: Homescreen(key: null),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: add code for `theme`.

Comment: Please take a look https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the default font family in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237031/how-to-change-the-default-font-family-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
theme: theme.copyWith(
        colorScheme: theme.colorScheme.copyWith(primary: Color(0xff075e54),secondary: Color(0xff128C7E)),
        textTheme: theme.textTheme.apply(fontFamily: "OpenSans"),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a style file in your dart folder and use the font where ever you want like this way-**text_styles.dart**

```
class TextStyles {
  static TextStyle overline(
      {required BuildContext context, required Color color}) {
    return GoogleFonts.montserrat(
      textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.overline?.copyWith(color: color),
    );
  }
}
```

and use it as-

```
TextStyles.overline(context: context, color: theme.textColor).copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
```

Note:if you use custom font you have to install the package from your pubspec.yaml.Example-

```
google_fonts:
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple file for the theme like the one I created **theme_util.dart** and use it as follows.

```
return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: appTheme,
      home: Homescreen(key: null),
 );
```

**theme_util.dart**

```
ThemeData appTheme = ThemeData(
  backgroundColor: appColor.white,
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: appColor.white,
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      color: appColor.white,
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      textTheme: TextTheme().copyWith(headline6: titleStyle),
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: appColor.primaryColor)),
  fontFamily: 'Opensans',
  primaryColor: appColor.primaryColor,
  primaryColorDark: appColor.primaryDarkColor,
  primaryColorLight: appColor.primaryLight,
  accentColor: appColor.accentColor,
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  //primarySwatch: appColor.blue,
  visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
  buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(buttonColor: appColor.primaryColor),
);
```

[image]