# How to use chinese fonts with chinese characters in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-font

I'm trying to show Chinese characters in my Flutter web app with Chinese font. Something like this.

[image]

After downloading the font ttf file, I applied it to my Chinese characters, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is how I apply my styling.

```dart
Text(
    "你好",
    style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: "Chinese",
        fontSize: 70,
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 234, 222, 218)
    ),
)
```

This is my pubspec.yaml file.

```yaml
fonts:
    - family: Chinese
      fonts:
      - asset: assets\fonts\MaShanZheng-Regular.ttf
```

The result.
[image]

How do I solve this? Much appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the default font family in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237031/how-to-change-the-default-font-family-in-flutter)

Comment: I would probably have missed out on the indentation in the pubspec file if it weren't for @mohammad esmaili answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pubspec is very sensitive about indentation:

```
  fonts:
    - family: Chinese
      fonts:
        - asset: assets\fonts\MaShanZheng-Regular.ttf
```

Make sure you have the right path too and got the font

Comment: This worked! However, I noticed I also did the same thing for other fonts for English characters. But those fonts were able to be applied, why is that?

Comment: well i think the fonts are supporting english language by default, due to the english is an international language, there are tons of fonts which will support it.